# Performance issue, stack, heap, or prototype pattern?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, prototype

I am coding a small game and want to polish my c++ and therefore i use every fancy design pattern i can find ;)

So now I assume I use the wrong pattern because I have heavy performance issues,

I use the prototype pattern for my enemy class which clones then different enemies, which must be drawn and updated....so...i want to append each alpha some minors dependent on their distance to them.... so all are enemies and I thought I search for each minor the nearest alpha enemy by for looping my vector of enemies.. .first for an minor and if i have a minor I am looking for the nearest alpha by looping again through the for loop to check for alpha types

```
class Enemy
{
public:
    virtual ~Enemy() {};
    virtual Enemy* clone() = 0;
...
    virtual void draw();

...
    void update(std::vector<Enemy*>& enemies);
```

and ...

```
void Enemy::update(std::vector<Enemy*>& enemies) {
    Enemy* closestAlpha = nullptr;
    for (int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++) {
        if (enemies[i]->getType() == eType::MINOR) {
            //Find the closest alpha
            closestAlpha = getNearestAlpha(enemies);

            // If we found a alpha, move towards him and join him
            if (closestAlpha != nullptr) {
                // Get the direction vector twoards the alpha

            }
        }
    }


}
```

and ...

```
Enemy* Enemy::getNearestAlpha(std::vector<Enemy*>& enemies) {

Enemy* closestAlpha = nullptr;
        float smallestDistance = 9999999.0f;

    for (int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++) {


}
}
```

So if I use this update function even I do nothing in the for loop, my fps drops to 5 fps and without this update function I got my desired 60 .

/**********************SOLVED****************************/
solved by using release mode and not debug ... counting now over 1000 objects

Comment: You're iterating over `enemies` and comparing type and then iterating over all `enemies` again, this seems very expensive. What is an Alpha? is this a type? if so you should filter the vector first, you need to explain more what you're attempting

Comment: Might be expensive but It is just a for loop ? I have two types of enemies, minors and alphas, i want to append each alpha some minors dependent on their distance to them.... so all are enemies I thought I search for each minor the nearest alpha enemy by for looping my vector of enemies

Comment: Unless you like guessing games, use a profiler.

Comment: it not just a for-loop. It is a textbook O(N^2) algorithm. If you are worried about performance, perhaps avoid that. And for heaven's sake, *profile*.

Comment: profiler says std::vector<Enemy *,std::allocator<Enemy *> >::operator[] 
and 
std::vector<Enemy *,std::allocator<Enemy *> >::size are using most time of the whole update function ...

Comment: I also find it strange to mix c++03 and c++11. If you want to iterate through the vector, then why don't you use for range loop, or for with iterators at least. It's not about performance, of course, but about *polish your c++*

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a separate class for holding and filtering your enemies.

```
// Just cause I can't be bothered to write std::vector.... all the time.
typedef std::vector<Enemy*>* enemyVector; 

class AllEnemies
{
public:
...
  // Checks Enemy's type and adds it to apropriate vector;
  void addEnemy(Enemy* e);
  enemyVector getMinors()
  enemyVector getAlphas()
...
private:
  enemyVector m_minors;
  enemyVector m_alphas;
};
```

You should also look into changing your data model. Some kind of spatial partitioning is usually used when dealing with these kinds of problems.
Check out [Nearest neighbor search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) and [R-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree)